# Conditional data selection in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a set of data by using query and in this data I need to select some data according to following condition

1. If SIGNSTAT = 4 then select all row which have SIGNSTAT = 4
2. Otherwise select latest create date row data.
   Please help to found the data

My query is as

```
 WITH CTE AS(SELECT C2C.NO AS CONTRACTNO,
           C.BRANCH,
           C.IDCLIENT,
           --C.PAN,
           C.NAMEONCARD,
           C.CREATEDATE,
           C.SIGNSTAT,
           ROW_NUMBER ()
              OVER (PARTITION BY C2C.NO ORDER BY C.CREATEDATE DESC)
              AS ROW_NUM
      FROM A4M.TCONTRACTCARDITEM C2C, A4M.TCARD C,A4M.TREFERENCECARDPRODUCT RCP
     WHERE 1 = 1 AND C.BRANCH = C2C.BRANCH AND C.PAN = C2C.PAN AND C2C.NO = '700000075333'
     AND C.BRANCH = RCP.BRANCH AND C.CARDPRODUCT = RCP.CODE
       AND UPPER(RCP.NAME) LIKE '%SUPPL%'
       )           
SELECT *  FROM CTE
--WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Result set:

```
CONTRACTNO  BRANCH  IDCLIENT    NAMEONCARD     CREATEDATE   SIGNSTAT ROW_NUM
700000075333    1   1215995 SAMIR CHANDRA DHAR  14-Jul-19   4          2
700000075333    1   1215995 SAMIR CHANDRA DHAR  20-Aug-19   3          1
```

Comment: Is hard to answer your question if you don't have any sample data.  However, it seem like what you want to do is two queries and than join them . One query will retrieve the signstat = 4 the other would retrieve signsta !=4 get the max date. you can join them or union them depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks! got the result

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
WITH data AS(SELECT C2C.NO AS CONTRACTNO,
           C.BRANCH,
           C.IDCLIENT,
           --C.PAN,
           C.NAMEONCARD,
           C.CREATEDATE,
           C.SIGNSTAT,
           ROW_NUMBER ()
              OVER (PARTITION BY C2C.NO ORDER BY C.CREATEDATE DESC)
              AS ROW_NUM
      FROM A4M.TCONTRACTCARDITEM C2C, A4M.TCARD C,A4M.TREFERENCECARDPRODUCT RCP
     WHERE 1 = 1 AND C.BRANCH = C2C.BRANCH AND C.PAN = C2C.PAN AND C2C.NO = '700000075333'
     AND C.BRANCH = RCP.BRANCH AND C.CARDPRODUCT = RCP.CODE
       AND UPPER(RCP.NAME) LIKE '%SUPPL%'
), cnt AS (SELECT COUNT(1) total
      FROM data
     WHERE SIGNSTAT=4)
SELECT * 
  FROM data
 WHERE SIGNSTAT=4
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM data
  JOIN cnt
    ON cnt.total=0
 WHERE data.ROW_NUM = 1
```

Comment: For single C2C.NO it work fine but for all C2C.NO some NO are not coming

Comment: I got the desired result by following query

Answer (score 0):

I got the desire result by following query

```
WITH data AS(SELECT C2C.NO AS CONTRACTNO,
       C.BRANCH,
       C.IDCLIENT,
       C.PAN,
       C.NAMEONCARD,
       C.CREATEDATE,
       C.SIGNSTAT,
       ROW_NUMBER ()
          OVER (PARTITION BY C2C.NO ORDER BY C.CREATEDATE DESC)
          AS ROW_NUM
  FROM A4M.TCONTRACTCARDITEM C2C, A4M.TCARD C,A4M.TREFERENCECARDPRODUCT RCP
 WHERE 1 = 1 AND C.BRANCH = C2C.BRANCH AND C.PAN = C2C.PAN AND C2C.NO = '700000075333'
 AND C.BRANCH = RCP.BRANCH AND C.CARDPRODUCT = RCP.CODE
   AND UPPER(RCP.NAME) LIKE '%SUPPL%') SELECT CONTRACTNO,BRANCH,IDCLIENT  FROM data WHERE SIGNSTAT=4 UNION ALL (SELECT CONTRACTNO,BRANCH,IDCLIENT  FROM data  WHERE data.ROW_NUM = 1 MINUS SELECT CONTRACTNO,BRANCH,IDCLIENT  FROM data WHERE SIGNSTAT=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with minor change in your original query. Use `CASE WHEN` as following:

```
WITH CTE AS(SELECT C2C.NO AS CONTRACTNO,
           C.BRANCH,
           C.IDCLIENT,
           --C.PAN,
           C.NAMEONCARD,
           C.CREATEDATE,
           C.SIGNSTAT,
           CASE WHEN C.SIGNSTAT = 4 THEN 1 ELSE ROW_NUMBER ()
              OVER (PARTITION BY C2C.NO ORDER BY C.CREATEDATE DESC) END
              AS ROW_NUM
      FROM A4M.TCONTRACTCARDITEM C2C, A4M.TCARD C,A4M.TREFERENCECARDPRODUCT RCP
     WHERE 1 = 1 AND C.BRANCH = C2C.BRANCH AND C.PAN = C2C.PAN AND C2C.NO = '700000075333'
     AND C.BRANCH = RCP.BRANCH AND C.CARDPRODUCT = RCP.CODE
       AND UPPER(RCP.NAME) LIKE '%SUPPL%'
       )           
SELECT *  FROM CTE
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: If any of these answers solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.